# C# image to URL throws an error 403

Tags: c#, authentication, amazon-s3, webrequest

When I put the following code in my program I get the 403 error

```
        var req = WebRequest.Create("http://floralegacy.s3.amazonaws.com/files2/449/44977-371x400.jpeg");

        using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
        }
```

anyone have an idea for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

403 indicates access denied which suggests that the bucket permissions might not allow non-authenticated access.

Try changing the bucket permissions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html

Comment: @lordrandom12 Then get the username and password, or an auth token.